# Is it possible to inherit a hidden ability and an egg move? Toxapex with Regenerator and Haze

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I'm following a guide to make a competitive Toxapex. This build requires Regenerator as a hidden ability and Haze as one of the moves in the moveset.

I have found a Toxapex that has the hidden ability in a raid, and I know I can breed a Toxapex with Haze if I have breeded it with a Wooper in advance.

But how do I breed now the one with the hidden ability and the one with the egg move? As far as I know, the hidden ability is only passed down if one of the parents is a Ditto. So if I breed these two together, I may inherit the move but I will lose the ability

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A ditto is only required to pass down (hidden) abilities if the non-ditto breeding partner is male or genderless.

So to breed a Toxapex with both Haze and Regenerator, you will need a female Toxapex with Regenerator (if the raid gave you a male, then breed it with a Ditto until you get a female with the hidden ability) and a compatible male with the desired egg move.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar

Comment: Bonus technique for getting egg-move : have one of the pokemons with the egg-move (and in the good egg-group) and put it near your hidden ability pokemon on the nursery. If you've got an available move slot, you'll get it

Comment: @LamaDelRay That only works if both of them are the same species, so you would have to breed it onto a Mareanie and evolve it frst.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Didn't know that thanks !